# cn1 - download file to phone's download directory

Tags: android, codenameone, download

I'm trying to allow an app to download files to the public 'Downloads' directory so it's available on the device in a generic fashion.  I succeeded in downloading the files in the simulator to the .cn1 directory on my computer, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to get the file into a public directory on the device.  I really expected there to be a method in the `FileSystemStorage` class that would allow this, but none of them seem to be what I'm looking for.

So I tried writing a simple native bridge to get the path to the public directory, starting with Android.  I have a very simple class that looks like this:

```
public class DownloadDirectoryImpl {

    public static String getDownloadDirectory(){
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public boolean isSupported(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

The app compiles fine, but when I click on the file to download it, I see the same line repeating itself in the logcat a few thousand times:

```
W/System.err:     at net.gesher.downloadDirectory.NativeDownloadDirectoryImpl.getDeviceDownloadDirectory(NativeDownloadDirectoryImpl.java:20)
```

But it doesn't state what the error is.

So, I'm looking for advice either a) to improve my android code so that it works, or b) the cn1 proper way of getting this directory path.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: That is a part of a longer stack trace. Please provide the full stack, you can see that full stack in the DDMS tool when the device is connected by scrolling within the console area.

Comment: I was able to scroll up to the top one time, and there's nothing before it that seems related or relevant.  At the end of a couple thousand lines like the one above, there's a stacktrace that traces through my code and then the cn1 code, back to java.lang, but it doesn't say what the exception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of lines saying at... and all refer to the same method then you have a recursive call leading to a stack overflow. Since the only method you mentioned is your native method I'm assuming you called your own method within the native implementation and got into a recursive loop.

Comment: I straightened out the code - I had not named the various native and corresponding cn1 files properly - and it suddenly worked!

Comment: Now I have another related issue, but maybe it should go in its own question.  Using `Util.downloadUrlToFile()` I try to download a file to the Downloads directory.  The method returns true, but nothing appears in my device's Downloads directory.  Nothing appears in the Logcat.

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I found the file on my device.  In Android image files aren't available through the 'Downloads' app, just in the gallery.